# Rails 5 - Whitelist Nested Field Params Generated from Looped Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Okay, so the problem I have here is that my params are looking funny because i'm looping through one of my form elements to create the fields.

Here's the code

`parent-new-form-creation.html.erb`

```
#other parts of parent form

<% @grandparent.friends.each do |g| %>
  <%= render "child_fields", f: builder %>
<% end %>
```

Now the problem here is that when the form is generated, the `Child_fields` fields would have IDs, such as:

```
<input name="parent[child_attributes][0][foo]" id="parent_child_attributes_0_foo" />
```

Now these IDs automatically generated for these inputs are messing up my params, because they end up looking like these when submitted:

```
"child_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"foo"=>"1", "moo"=>"A"}, "1"=>{"foo"=>"0", "moo"=>"A1"}}
```

Now i'm rather certain that the other "regular" aspects of accepting nested attributes are set up properly. Its just this whitelisting portion of the params during the creation which is giving me some trouble, seeing as how i have no idea how i.

I feel like i need to amend my params, but i'm not quite sure how. It's currently

```
child_attributes: [:foo, :moo]
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: why don't you try using accept_nested_attributes refer eg: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-has-many-through

Comment: @VishalTajPM sorry but i don't see how that solves my problem. Maybe you could elaborate? Right now my trouble is with my params being submitted, and not because there's validation errors. Afaik, :inverse_of is used to solve a persistence problem, mainly because when creating the child, the parent has not hit the database (and in rails5, the belongs_to relation is enforced and a parent object is needed when creating the child).

Comment: `accept_nested_attributes` takes care of child field persistence for you, so you just save the parent object. `fields_for` and `accept_nested_attributes` are intended to work in conjunction to achieve seamless related model creation.

Comment: If you're battling against Rails 5's belongs_to enforcement, before going through too many hurdles I would just override that behavior by passing it along as optional: `belongs_to :grandparents, optional: true`

Comment: @DanielWestendorf oh yes i am actually aware of that. I was just responding the Vishal regarding his comment and how it was not applicable to the current problem i'm facing...

Comment: @Schwad i'm not actually... in the question the problem i'm facing is Rails form generators creating IDs for form elements, resulting in weird params which i do not know how to handle...